# Form difference in MVC and .NET 2

Tags: .net, forms, model-view-controller

I have just started to learn MVC. But I have worked a bit with .NET 2.0

I have difficult to understand the way Forms is created in MVC.

I have seen examples, where you first make a class of Form data with propperties  and then use  them to create Form.

Is it necessary ?
Is it possible to create Forms, as I did in .Net 2.0 ?

If you have only a search box on the page, do i have to create a class of it first?

```
public class FormData
{
  [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength=2, ErrorMessage="* A valid first name is   
    required.")]
    [Display(Name="First Name")]
    public string TextBoxStringData { get; set; }

    public int TextBoxIntData { get; set; }

    public bool CheckboxData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you need to understand how MVC works.
Don't think in terms of forms. Think in terms of Model. MVC means Model View Controller right? You need to understand their role. The Model is the data that the View needs to function or needs to capture in a form for example.

So, if you want a form, first create a Model class with the fields that you want. If you have a username / password form, you wold create a LoginModel with 2 properties, one for each field.

After you create the model make sure you build the app. The easiest way to create a form is use the Visual Studio menu. Add new item / Form. There it will ask you what kind of form you need so you can select Create for example. Then it will ask you what model class you want to use. There you select your LoginModel. Once you create it, it will basically create the whole form for you with the right fields and validation.

Now, each form needs two controller methods to function. One used to simply load the view with the form, the second needs a Post tag on it and it will be hit once you click the submit button on your form. The input for this method will be your LoginModel because MVC knows exactly what model class your form uses. you can verify this by putting a breakpoint on your post method and you'll see the data from the form in your input parameter.

Hopefully this makes sense but I do suggest to start with an MVC tutorial. Webforms and MVC are completely different beats